# how to write multiple AND OR inside an if statement?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, logical-operators

I am trying to write a PowerShell script for my SharePoint 2013. The idea is that I want to select all the links that are referencing a `/documents/` folder, and that end with either `.doc`, `.docx`, or `.pdf`, so I wrote the following `if` statement:

```
$links = $file.ForwardLinks;
foreach ($link in $links) {
    if ($link.url -like '*/Documents/*' -and ($link.url -like '.doc' -or $link.url -like '.docx'  -or $link.url -like '.pdf')) {
```

Is my use of `-and` & `-or` correct?

Comment: Have you tried running it and see if the result matches what you expect? I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: the above will not return any result,, i mean no link will pass the if statement,, even i have links that contain both /documents/ & .pdf for example

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do `$link.url -like '*.doc'` etc.

Comment: if you add the wildcards like chrono suggests it should work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of your clauses is correct: `A -and (B -or C -or D)`. However, for partial matches with the `-like` operator you need wildcards in the strings, otherwise the operator will behave the same as the `-eq` operator.

```psh
if (
  $link.url -like '*/Documents/*' -and
  ($link.url -like '*.doc' -or $link.url -like '*.docx' -or $link.url -like '*.pdf')
) {
  ...
}
```

However, in your case a better approach might be to extract the extension from the URL and check if it's contained in a list of extensions:

```psh
$extensions = '.doc', '.docx', '.pdf'

$ext = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($link.url)
if ($link.url -like '*/Documents/*' -and $extensions -contains $ext) {
  ...
}
```